# Looks like a case of serial upvoting... or something else

Tags: discussion, users, serial-voting

I recently discovered a user's reputation tab which looked like the following:

*(Questions are voted twice, but every time the votes are casted at same time i.e., 15:10 and 15:02)*

[image: redacted reputation timeline]

*(Answers are voted once, but again all at the same time)*

[image]

> Note that I've *blacked* the names in order to *not* expose the user. If I'll find my suspect right (i.e., serial upvoting), then I will provide the details.

First, I thought that this could be case of serial upvoting, but then I noted that questions are serially voted twice, which means that there are **two voters involved**. But, why on the Earth will two users serially vote **exactly the same questions**?

Therefore, on support of the above fact, I think that possibly the user is having **multiple profiles**!

Am I missing something? **OR** have I made the correct interpretation?

Comment: You should really work on your redacting skills.

Comment: Maybe you found something, maybe you didn't..... you'll only know when you make a custom mod flag to say what you found. We can't help further than that

Comment: Ok I'm just going to raise a flag. But I want to know if this is serial-voting or not

Comment: This does look fishy indeed. You should flag one of the up-voted posts for moderator attention. Link to this meta/screenshot in the message to the moderator.

Comment: If you looked at the negative reputation entry one day above, you will see that there is also a lot of minus for voting correction and a link to learn more about voting correction.

Comment: @Codeer, wait... how do you know that? (i suppose i've not provided any detail) :0. I know that the votes were corrected the next day, but on Oct 16 and Oct 8, there were serial-voting, but none of them corrected the next day

Comment: @rv7 on October 25th a sizeable amount of reputation was deducted (198/200 that was earned the day before and that's is what you are suspicious about). That is - I believe - what Codeer was talking about.

Comment: @rv you haven't _quite_ blacked out the details. That was Script47 first comment about. Let's just say that we know the user id of that user ends in 18.

Comment: @yivi yes it is. Thanks for editing :)